# When independent variables covary (not correlate) in the regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I attach r code

```
x1<-rnorm(999,0,1)
x2<-rnorm(999,0,1)
y <- x1+x2
iv1<-999999*x1
iv2<-999999*x2

cov(x1,x2) # nearly 0
cor(x1,x2) # nearly 0
cov(iv1,iv2) # very big, 
cor(iv1,iv2) # nearly 0

summary(lm(y~x1+x2+x1*x2)) # interaction p=0.11

summary(lm(y~iv1+iv2+iv1:iv2)) #interaction significant.
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x1 * x2)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-3.959e-14 -1.150e-16  1.400e-17  9.100e-17  4.756e-14 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -7.728e-17  6.269e-17 -1.233e+00    0.218    
x1           1.000e+00  6.090e-17  1.642e+16   <2e-16 ***
x2           1.000e+00  6.474e-17  1.545e+16   <2e-16 ***
x1:x2       -1.027e-16  6.630e-17 -1.550e+00    0.122    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.976e-15 on 995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.631e+32 on 3 and 995 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(lm(y~iv1+iv2+iv1:iv2))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv1:iv2)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-4.137e-14 -1.010e-16  2.100e-17  1.050e-16  3.623e-14 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -7.728e-17  5.581e-17 -1.385e+00   0.1665    
iv1          1.000e-06  5.422e-23  1.844e+16   <2e-16 ***
iv2          1.000e-06  5.764e-23  1.735e+16   <2e-16 ***
iv1:iv2     -1.217e-28  5.902e-29 -2.062e+00   0.0395 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.759e-15 on 995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 2.058e+32 on 3 and 995 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

when I make y, I did not put interaction effect.
but why x1:x2 interaction show tendency (p=0.11)
and why iv1:iv2 interaction is significant?

Comment: You also didn't put any errors in the response *y* and you ignore a warning message about "essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable". So there may not much to learn from this simulation.

Comment: It's also a fallacy to interpret a p-value of ~0.1 as "showing tendency".

Comment: @dipetkov I did not put error variance, but in my real simulation work, I put error variance. this is a kind of minimum reproducible example to understand what is really happening in my real model.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the attempt to make a reproducible example, this helps to diagnose problems. However, it's important for you to set a seed using `set.seed()` so we can reproduce an example exactly. Here, I cannot reproduce your example.

Let's see what happens when we set a seed and run your code:

```
set.seed(52)
x1<-rnorm(999,0,1)
x2<-rnorm(999,0,1)
y <- x1+x2
iv1<-999999*x1
iv2<-999999*x2

# First model
summary(lm(y~x1+x2+x1:x2)) 
# NOTE that I have replaced your asterisk with a colon in the formula above
# R appears to interpret both the same way so this does not really change anything meaningful

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-1.307e-15 -1.790e-16 -5.700e-17  2.500e-17  7.211e-14 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.897e-16  7.499e-17 2.529e+00   0.0116 *  
x1          1.000e+00  7.406e-17 1.350e+16   <2e-16 ***
x2          1.000e+00  7.778e-17 1.286e+16   <2e-16 ***
x1:x2       2.145e-17  7.714e-17 2.780e-01   0.7810    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.365e-15 on 995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.122e+32 on 3 and 995 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

summary(lm(y~iv1+iv2+iv1:iv2))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv1:iv2)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-1.226e-15 -2.200e-16 -9.000e-17  9.000e-18  7.736e-14 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.459e-16  9.008e-17  2.730e+00  0.00645 ** 
iv1          1.000e-06  8.896e-23  1.124e+16  < 2e-16 ***
iv2          1.000e-06  9.342e-23  1.070e+16  < 2e-16 ***
iv1:iv2     -7.233e-30  9.266e-29 -7.800e-02  0.93780    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.84e-15 on 995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 7.778e+31 on 3 and 995 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


# Second model:

summary(lm(y~iv1+iv2+iv1:iv2))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv1:iv2)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-1.226e-15 -2.200e-16 -9.000e-17  9.000e-18  7.736e-14 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.459e-16  9.008e-17  2.730e+00  0.00645 ** 
iv1          1.000e-06  8.896e-23  1.124e+16  < 2e-16 ***
iv2          1.000e-06  9.342e-23  1.070e+16  < 2e-16 ***
iv1:iv2     -7.233e-30  9.266e-29 -7.800e-02  0.93780    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.84e-15 on 995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 7.778e+31 on 3 and 995 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

No difference between the models. But as dipetikov points out, there could be algorithmic problems here because there's no random error - you have defined `y` as the exact sum of `x1` and `x2`. This can *sometimes* cause that 'summary may be unreliable' error (I did not get it with this seed though). So let's retry this with some random error added.

```
set.seed(52)
x1<-rnorm(999,0,1)
x2<-rnorm(999,0,1)
y <- x1+x2 + rnorm(999, 0, 0.3)
iv1<-999999*x1
iv2<-999999*x2

#First model
summary(lm(y~x1+x2+x1:x2)) 

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.94731 -0.20592 -0.00382  0.19295  1.17179 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.001034   0.009457  -0.109    0.913    
x1           1.000205   0.009340 107.091   <2e-16 ***
x2           0.999198   0.009808 101.873   <2e-16 ***
x1:x2        0.001398   0.009728   0.144    0.886    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2982 on 995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9551,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9549 
F-statistic:  7050 on 3 and 995 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

#Second model
summary(lm(y~iv1+iv2+iv1:iv2))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv1:iv2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.94731 -0.20592 -0.00382  0.19295  1.17179 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.034e-03  9.457e-03  -0.109    0.913    
iv1          1.000e-06  9.340e-09 107.091   <2e-16 ***
iv2          9.992e-07  9.808e-09 101.873   <2e-16 ***
iv1:iv2      1.398e-15  9.728e-15   0.144    0.886    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2982 on 995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9551,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9549 
F-statistic:  7050 on 3 and 995 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Again, I don't see a problem - the results in both cases are good. To be sure it's not because you used an asterisk for one model and a colon for the other, I retried this your way (with the same seed) but still got the same (good) results.